# Example of how to architect side-navigation using Polymer in a Chrome App?

Tags: polymer, google-chrome-app

I am building a Chrome App. I would like to construct the UI using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/). I like the side navigation they show in the [example web app in the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up): a left nav bar of items that that changes the content in the main window.

I am struggling to get this working with the restrictions placed on Chrome Apps. Apps face a rigorous Content Security Policy (CSP) that forbids use of eval, inline scripts, and `window.history` operations.

I've made some progress over the past few hours, but have run into a host of problems. Starting with their demo code, I can get the app to render the side navigation bar but not the content cards. I'm using `vulcanize` and `crisper`, but still haven't managed to get it working. If it's not a 404 (why is it loading files if I'm importing them?), it's a suspicious "Refused to evaluate a string as Javascript" warning that seems tied to the seemingly innocuous line `var noop = Function();` in the Polymer library itself.

Does anyone know of basic, Chrome App-friendly examples of this architecture that they can point me to? It seems very basic, and yet it's proving difficult.

Comment: Try googling for [other](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymerchromeapp) examples.

Comment: Good point. This helps me clarify my question, which I recognize is vague. Unfortunately I don't understand Polymer enough to know exactly what I'm struggling with--my struggles are vague. I've found that example already, and I know that it is possible to use at least some Polymer elements in Chrome Apps. However, that isn't a solution for two reasons. First, that is a long-derelict version of Polymer. Second, from what I understand of the framework I can't just swap their `paper-tabs` nav system for a left nav bar. I'm looking for a left-nav architecture that is Chrome-App-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, day 2 of struggling led to some modest success. I am now able to display their [demo sidebar navigation app](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up) in a Chrome App. Several things had to be changed.

First, the `window.history` family of APIs is not available on Chrome Apps. As a result, the `<app-location>` tag they use for routing does not work, as it relies on the location and apparently leverages the `window.history` API. Instead, I removed that tag and am somehow managing to successfully use databinding as routing. Here is the relevant portion of `my-app.html`. The main things that changed are removing `<app-location>` (which I leave commented out here for clarity), and changing the `selected` databinding attributes from `[[page]]` to `{{page}}`. The curly brace allows for two-way bindings. I **believe** that this is necessary to allow the `<iron-selector>` element to send the `page` variable to the `<iron-pages>` element.

```
<!-- <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location> -->
<app-route
    route="{{page}}"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer>
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="{{page}}" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="view1" >View One</a>
      <a name="view2" >View Two</a>
      <a name="view3" >View Three</a>
      <a name="new-view" href="/new-view">New View</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="{{page}}" attr-for-selected="name">
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
      <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
      <my-new-view name="new-view"></my-new-view>
    </iron-pages>

  </app-header-layout>

</app-drawer-layout>
```

After the `vulcanize` and `crisper` process shown below, this allowed the navbar to be displayed when loaded as a Chrome App. However, the pages themselves (as controlled by `<iron-pages>`) would not load. This was due to the fact that the demo tries to be user friendly by dynamically performing HTML imports. This confuses the Chrome App due to path issues (and possibly URL loading restrictions--I'm not sure). Instead, we are going to manually import them. This will allow `vulcanize` to work its magic. Add the following lines to the rest of the imports at the top of `src/my-app.html`

```
<link rel="import" href="my-view1.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-view2.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-view3.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-new-view.html">
```

Finally, remove the `observer: '_pageChanged'` and the `_pageChanged` function itself from the script portion of `srv/my-app.html`.

We're getting close.

Chrome Apps have a strict Content Security Policy that prevents the execution of inline scripts (i.e. scripts in `<script>` tags). Polymer makes heavy use of inline scripts, so the framework authors have provided a tool to get around this problem.

[vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) walks HTML import statements to try and reduce network loads. [crisper](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper) extracts all the inline scripts and cats them to a single `<script>` tag with the `src` attribute, allowing it to execute in Chrome Apps. The following line replaces the existing `index.html` with one safe for Chrome Apps. (Note REPLACES, so be make sure you copy your original `index.html` first.)

`vulcanize --inline-scripts --inline-css index.html | crisper --html index.html --js index.js`

Now we have an `index.html` without any inline scripts that can render as a Chrome App. As of 2016-07-30, two problems remain. The first is that Polymer tries to register a service worker. Open `index.js` and remove the `serviceWorker.register` call. Second, find the definition of `_boundEffect` in `index.js`. For some reason, Chrome Apps think that `var noop = Function();` requires `eval`, and it doesn't execute it. Replace this line with `var noop = () => {}`. This is basically the same thing, but for some reason Chrome Apps allows it.

After all this, load `index.html` in your Chrome App and the demo works.

Huzzah.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect do you need to use it or do you just think it would strengthen the response?